# "segfault" error from random seed number?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, random-seed

So, my code randomly started having an issue when it tried to read an input file using the following lines:

```
char inputName[20] = "params.txt";
FILE *inputFile = fopen(inputName, "r");
char *ptr;
```

The code is supposed to open a text file, where the following lines of code:

```
int count = 1;
char singleLine[10];
double parameters[4];
while (count < 5){
    parameters[count] = strtod(fgets(singleLine, 10, inputFile), &ptr);
    count = count + +1;
}
h = parameters[1];
N_steps = parameters[2];
titleNumber = parameters[3];
seed_number = parameters[4];
fclose(inputFile);
inputFile = 0;
```

And assigns the following values from a .txt files to variables

1.0

100000

1000

33

With the last integer being used as the seed number for the srand() function.  However, I have found that some 4-digit and above integers for the seed value cause the code to generate a segmentation fault error.  Does anyone know why that is?  Is there a range of acceptable seed values for the random number generator function in c?

Comment: Indices in C start from 0. If you have an array with N elements then the valid range of indices is [0, N).

Answer (score 1):

Indices for arrays in C start from `0`. If you have an array with `N` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N)`.

So relative to your code snippet the valid range of indices for this array

```
double parameters[4];
```

is `[0, 4 )`. The expression `parameters[4]` accesses memory beyond the array that results in undefined behavior.